# Are topological vacua of QCD Lorentz invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, quantum-chromodynamics, topology

Are topological vacua of QCD Lorentz invariant or they mix under boosts?

Comment: "Topological vacuum" is not a technical term with a precise meaning (that I would know). Are you talking about the vacua associated to instantons? As topological objects, how could boosts possibly act non-trivially on them (i.e. what's the quantitiy associated to them that is not a Lorentz scalar)? Please elaborate on your question to make it more accessible.

Comment: Yes, I mean topological vacua related to instantons. Instantons seems to me to be truely invariant objects. But topological vacua are defined in an obviously noivariant way: in the temporal gauge and on the surface of constant time. Both conditions violate Lorentz invariance. On the other hand, topology should not depend on boost. I am confused.

Comment: One may look for a static kink solution which saturates the Bogomol’nyi bound and because the Lagrangian is Lorentz invariant, he may boost it to find a class of them.